# PhpStorm method not found depends in the order?

Tags: phpstorm

As you can see in the picture, if I change the order the error is gone. Why does this happens?

[image: a error]

Method 'viewVars' not found in more

Answer (score 1):

Most probable cause would be that one of the fluent interface methods has different return type hint. It may for example return interface instead of the actual implementation, that may be missing the method.